# Excel CONCAT Columns B and C While they have Similar Values at Column A

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can you please let me know how I can CONCAT two Columns values while the Column **A** has similar values in each rows in excel?
Something like following, what I need is to CONCAT values of rows in Columns **B** and **C** while the **A** is similar

[image]

Comment: You can use `FILTER` and `TEXTJOIN` if you have those functions.  What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: On newer Excel, using `UNIQUE` on that first column within the filter formula should get the formula to spill so you wouldn't have those row spaces...

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `CONCAT()`, the following will do the trick:

```
=LEFT(CONCAT((CHAR(34)&FILTER($B$1:$C21,$A$1:$A21=E1)&CHAR(34))&I1:J1), 
LEN(CONCAT((CHAR(34)&FILTER($B$1:$C21,$A$1:$A21=E1)&CHAR(34))&I1:J1))-1)
```

It requires using `UNIQUE()` in E1 on a range, A1:C15 to `SPILL` a list of the... unique... elements in the first column, then is entered in some cell, say F1, and copied down the column until no more unique elements of E1# are present. The formula uses `FILTER()` to get all the elements in the second and third columns whose column A value matches that line's E1# result. The `"` (doublequote) characters are added with a simple string joining building the input to `CONCAT()`. Everything `CONCAT()` will process is inside its own set of parentheses ( `()` ) so it can have something appended in a way that appends to each element, not the whole result only.

The "magic" happens when you append to each string element `CONCAT()` generates. Instead of a single character, either the colon or the comma, then figuring out how to change the right half of them to other character, I used the range I1:J1 which hold a colon and a comma, respectively. I could have hardcoded them with `&{":",","}` instead of `&I1:J1`, but if you prefer...

So then you have the whole problem of doing this with `CONCAT()`:  the appended character ending the string due to appending a character after EVERY element and it being unable to deal differently with the last element. Hence the preference for `TEXTJOIN()` which does not have that problem. Here I approached it with a hammer and bludgeoned it away:  I used `LEFT()` to keep all the string except that last character, hence the second parameter of `LEFT()` being the length of the string minus 1.

If you CAN use `TEXTJOIN()`, the following formula is for you:

```
=TEXTJOIN($I$1:$J$1,TRUE,CHAR(34)&FILTER($B$1:$C15,$A$1:$A15=E1)&CHAR(34))
```

Again, you can hardcode the first parameter, those delimiters you use. I'll take a moment to say that, for all I know, your language version of Excel, or Windows, may use those for delimiters, ":" between same-column cells and "," demarking a jump to a new row. Still, since you want to specify two delimiters, you can't rely upon system defaults anyway, so...

Oh, last thought:  you see the `CHAR(34)` bits used to add those doublequotes. I used them in preference to fiddling with how many doublequotes to type to get Excel to prepend and append single `"` characters. You may prefer fiddling. Also, possibly you show them as an artifact of building strings to hand place to create your example of desired output and don't really want everything doublequoted. If that is the case, in either formula you just remove those bits and you are set.